# Same row space is equivalent to same column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices that have the same row space, then $A$ and $B$ have the same column space.

This is false of course. I could just come up with examples though. Can one prove this?

Comment: A counterexample to a claim *is* a proof that the claim is false.

Comment: Yes. I do acknowledge that. But is there any other way of ruling it out? Theorems of any sort, induction, reasoning? I kind of cheated by looking at the counterexample given in the book. So, I'm trying to find another way to think of this on my own.

Comment: If you want to be precise, the column space and the row space are subspaces of different vector spaces (but they are isomorphic), so they can't be equal.

Comment: Hmm. The problem specifies that the matrix is nxn. So, should the subspaces not be the same vector spaces? What do you mean by isomorphic? I made a quick Google definition: same size/shape.

Comment: Like I said, if you want to be precise, then they are different vector spaces. Given your question, I'm assuming you are not yet aware of such things, so you shouldn't worry too much about it and think of both the row space and column space as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (you may want to clarify this with your lecturer though). Basically, the space of row vectors and the space of column vectors are not the same, but they can be identified. In a first linear algebra course, this identification is made implicitly, so you aren't even aware it has been done.

Comment: Do I really just have to stick to the counterexamples :( ? I thought I could have some more fun.

Comment: In general elementary row operations on a matrix leave the row space unchanged but they (in some cases) change the column space.

Comment: OF COURSE! How great that you made me think of that :)

Comment: @hardmath: You are completely correct, I did misread the question. My apologies.

Comment: Forum, what if the column space is the same? Will the row space be the same?

Comment: @yolo123 To answer your last question, just transpose the matrices, and your question reverts back to the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theory tells us that if the row space of $A$ equals the row space of $B$, then the *ranks* of the column spaces of $A$ and $B$ are equal.  Let this guide us to a minimal counterexample.

Clearly if the dimensions of the column spaces were zero, then indeed the columns spaces would be trivial (and equal).  So the minimal counterexample involves dimension (at least) one.

What do rank one matrices with the same row space as $A$ look like?  Do any of them have different columns spaces?  (Hint: yes.)

If you know matrix multiplication, here's an easy way to build a pair of matrices with the same one-dimensional row space but different column spaces.  Pick a nonzero row vector $v$ of length $n$.  Pick two nonzero column vectors $u^T$ and $w^T$, also of length $n$, which are not scalar multiples of one another (so the spaces spanned by $u^T$ and $w^T$ are not equal).

Let $A = u^T v$ and $B = w^T v$.  Then the row spaces of $A$ and $B$ are both the one-dimensional space spanned by $\{v\}$, but the column spaces are different.  The column space of $A$ is the space spanned by $\{u^T\}$, while the column space of $B$ is the space spanned by $\{w^T\}$, and we just arranged that these would be distinct.

Note that all the rows of $A$ and all the rows of $B$ are scalar multiples of $v$, and in each case there is at least one nonzero row.  This proves the claim about the row spaces of $A$ and $B$ being the same.  Similarly the column space of $A$ is the span of $\{u^T\}$ and the column space of $B$ is the span of $\{w^T\}$.

Any doubt about reversing the roles of row and column spaces should be dispelled by taking the transposes of $A$ and $B$, or $A^T$ and $B^T$ as we usually denote them.  These last two $n\times n$ matrices will have equal column spaces but different row spaces.

Comment: I do have an additional question: what about the reverse? What if the column space is the same? Will the row space be the same?

(By the way, I have not studied ranks (yet! It is scheduled for next week. But I will definitely come back to your proof.))

Comment: @yolo123: I updated my answer to better address your probable level of study, and I tackle switching the roles of row and column by using *transposes*.  Hopefully you have studied this, which amounts to swapping the rows and columns of a matrix.

Comment: Perfect. I did study transposes. :)

Comment: What do you mean by length n? What happens if they are not of length n?

Comment: By the way, another aside question: what is meant by the multiplication of two vectors? Is it equivalent to the cross-product, the dot-product or what exactly happens!?

Comment: This is just the usual matrix multiplication, where the "column vector" $u^T$ is size $n\times 1$ and the "row vector" $v$ is size $1\times n$.  Thus their product is $n\times n$, with each entry in the product being just an entry from $u^T$ times an entry from $v$.