# Same column space is equivalent to same row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices that have the same column space, then $A$ and $B$ have the same row space.

Can one prove or disprove this? This is my continuation of [Same row space is equivalent to same column space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908251/same-row-space-is-equivalent-to-same-column-space)

Answer (score 3):

False:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

and, $B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Any other methods of disproving this without counterexamples?

Comment: @yolo123: Disprove usually means "give a counterexample that doesn't work". Of course- there might be some theorems that say the conjecture is false. However, in this case- there are examples where the conjecture is true- and hence the best method is to give a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If two $n\times n$ matrices have the same column space, then there is a sequence of elementary column operations transforming one matrix to the other. But column operations need not preserve the row space of a matrix.